# menu-item class missing on wordpress menu

Tags: menus, filters, headers

I have this code in my header.php and its working properly except showing li's without menu-item class, its showing them with page-item instead. this is when i dont have a menu created from admin and assigned it to a menu location.

So the menu is wordpress default menu which shows all the pages added. Is there a way to add menu item class with them.

I tried following code but its not working.

```
function li_nav_class($classes, $item, $args){
    $classes[] = 'menu-item ';
   return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'li_nav_class' , 1 , 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The default fallback in `wp_nav_menu` for a menu that doesn't exist/isn't registered is [`wp_page_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_page_menu/), which unfortunately does not support the same arguments/implement the same level of "customisability" - you either need to create a custom fallback, or remove the fallback entirely (so that the user is forced to set a menu).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code with required modifications

```
<?php
           if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :
              wp_nav_menu(['theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => 'nav']);
           endif;
        ?>
```

for adding class to ul : `'menu_class' => 'nav'`

Also try [this](http://sevenspark.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-a-wordpress-menu-item) link.